# Populating a checkbox from a table of category matches in PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of categories associated with a post in a database. Here is an example of what the categories look like in the database (PID = PostID and CATID = Category ID).

```
PID   CATID
 1      34
 1      12
 1      15
```

I have a php form that displays a list of all categories next to an array of checkboxes using `name = "catid[]"`. I need to know the best practice to query the database and and write PHP code so that it pre-check the boxes for categories `12`, `15`, and `34` using the `CHECKED` attribute in each appropriate form checkbox for the POST with an `PID` of `1`.

Here is the function that produces the list of categories.

```
function categoryTree($pid, $cat_type, $parentid = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
global $db;

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentid = $parentid and cat_type = '$cat_type' ORDER BY parentid, category ASC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row['parentid'] == 0) {
            echo '<div><label><span class="font-md">'.$sub_mark.$row['category']."</span></label></div>";
        } else {
            echo '<div class="checkbox" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;"><label><input name="catid[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['catid'].'" class="checkbox style-0"><span>'.$sub_mark.$row['category']."</span></label></div>";
        }
        categoryTree($cat_type, $row['catid'], $sub_mark.' ');
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code and read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the array of checked categories ids as `$checkedCategories` you could do something like this.

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
   <input name="catid[]" 
       value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" 
       <?php echo in_array($category['id'], $checkedCategories)? 'checked':'' ?>>
   <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
   <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```